# How to fix the footer on bottom of the page in react-native?

Tags: css, react-native

I want to fix the footer on the bottom of the page,

Thats why my whole container was in `flex:1` so it takes all the space,

and in my footer, i added `position:"absolute",marginBottom:0,`, the footer affected so badly which i didnt expect. It goes to up like in the header of the page, then i deleted it,

How can i fix it on bottom of page?

Here is the related code.

```
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:"#ffffff", }}>
{/* Footer */}
        <View style={{ flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"space-between",marginHorizontal:35,}}>
        <View> // here there are some code
         <View> 
          <Home height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <Ratio height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <Time height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <User height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />

        </View>   

      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
```

Here how the page seen:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. In react-native, if you use position absolute, you should give it a width and height.

Comment: it still doesnt work when i use width, height, i  add marginBottom:0, no, it doesnt go bottom

Comment: you should use bottom:0, but not margin-bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Position is from the css language.

```
{
  position:"absolute",
  bottom:0
}
```

Comment: To be honest, it doesnt work properly. I have a page, and i have a button in that page, when i write position:absolute, and bottom:0, footer doesnt stay at bottom:0 it happens like this(adding pic on question), do you know how i could change it?

Comment: Which one is the footer? You can describe your question more clearly. Better paste more code.

Comment: sorry i just read messages, the whole code in my question was for footer,

Answer (score 1):

here is my code for fixed footer

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
/// some Code
</ScrollView>

// here is bottom bar

<View style={{height: 60, justifyContent: 'center', borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderTopRightRadius: 20, flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>

<View style={{flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'}}>

//Here is you bottom icon or image
<View>

</View>

</View>
```

Comment: You want the footer fixed at the bottom of the scrollview?

Comment: Maybe you can add some comment show which is the footer?And keep footer scrollview bottombar together.

Comment: If your scrollview content is longer than the window height,will should the footer lay?

Comment: So your problem is what?

Answer (score 1):

The position is from the CSS language.

```
{
  position:"absolute",
  bottom:0,
  height: 60
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how does your post differ from gwl002's post?